# How do I use the querySelector?

Tags: javascript, function

So I got this code:

```
Function9() {
            x = document.getElementById('BakjeRood');
            x.style.opacity=1;
            y = document.querySelectorAll("#BakjeBlauw, #BakjeGeel, #BakjePaars, #BakjeRoze, #BakjeWit");
            y.style. opacity = 0;
        }
```

If you click the button with function9() the image 'BakjeRood' gets an opacity of 1, but the other images (BakjeBlauw etc.) should then get an opacity of 0 (this  structure is the same for all the functions I have on my site. How do I get this second part to work?

Comment: A collection is returned, hence the `All` part of `querySelectorAll`. So iterate the result.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you've illustrated a knowledge of `getElementById`, which by nature returns a single `HTMLElement` instance or derivative, whereas `querySelectorAll` returns an enumerable, list/array-like object, containing all `HTMLElement` instances that match the query.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#x, #z, #z");
for(var index = 0; index < elems.length; index++) {
    elems[index].style.opacity = 0;
    elems[index].canDoOtherStuffToo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the results of `querySelectorAll` - it returns an array-like object (a list of nodes), not a single node.